# Python - Using list outside function

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

Following on from my previous question: [Python - different variable with each function run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403178/python-different-variable-with-each-function-run/21403296#21403296)

I can now run the function multiple times and append to a list which is great. The problem now, is accessing the list outside of the function.

```
def TwoPic():
    run = 0
    Lats = []
    Longs = []
    while run < 2:
        run = run + 1
        print ("Start func TwoPic")
        oneMorePic()
        Lats.append(finalLatSecondPhoto)
        Longs.append(finalLongSecondPhoto)

        print '\n\nYour coordinates: ' + rippedLatitudeTwo + ',-' + rippedLongitudeTwo
        print "Below are the 2 new lats and longs in a list"
        print Lats
        print Longs
        root.quit()
    return Lats, Longs

root = Tk() 

label = Label(root, text="Choose Iterations", font=('Calibri', 12))
button1 = Button(root, text = "0 Pics", command = Quit)
button2 = Button(root, text = "1 Pic", command = OnePic)
button3 = Button(root, text = "2 Pics", command = TwoPic)

label.pack()
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
button3.pack()
root.mainloop() 

print "List: "

print Lats, Longs # Should print my list....I'm now outside of the function
```

Error:

```
Your coordinates: 43 48.54,-1 24.58
Below are the 2 new lats and longs in a list
[43.809, 43.809]
[1.409, 1.409]
List:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simonsScript.py", line 447, in <module>
    print Lats, Longs
NameError: name 'Lats' is not defined
```

Why is it not letting me print the list outside of the function?

Comment: `Lats` and `Longs` defined inside `TwoPic()` scope they are not global, you are trying to access variable that is not defined.

Comment: Before `print` you need to call `Lats, Longs = TwoPic()`

Comment: *`"I can now run the function multiple times and append to a list which is great"`* Remember in different function calls you are redefining  `Lats`, `Longs` lists in-side function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Lats` variable is not in scope when you try to print it.
Try to define it outside the function (**note**: it's rarely a good idea to have "global" variables; I assume you know what you're doing, and that you have no other sane choice).

```
Lats = []

def TwoPic():
    run = 0
    [...]

print Lats
```

Also, it's not good practice to define variables with a capital letter. Of course it depends on your naming convention, but it might be easier to read other people's code in the future if you get used to common practices.

This means:

```
lats = []
def two_pic():
    run = 0
    [...]

print lats,long..
```

If you want to know more about good coding practices for python (not necessarily related to naming variables) search for "pep8" or look at this [link](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thanks I see what I did wrong now. I normally do use camelCase. For this instance I was more focussed on getting the code working than the case. I'll go back and fix all that now. Thanks again.

Comment: actually that solution is not really a good one, try to always avoid using global scoped variables! If you really need, then create a class!

Comment: @zmo you're right, that is a bad solution, but since there are buttons and labels involved I assumed there were other constraints. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it not letting me print the list outside of the function?

Because it's a local name that only exists within the function (and FIY your `Lats` and `Longs` list only lives for the duration of the function's execution.

Answer (score 0):

Lats and Longs defined inside TwoPic() scope they are not global, you are trying to access variable that is not defined.

Change you code to first define them by the function you made and then print their value.

```
Lats, Longs = TwoPic() 
print "Lists:", Lats, Longs
```

Comment: actually I think they should only be defined as soon as the button was pressed. The whole print should be part of the `TwoPic()` function.

Comment: @hochl I accept the suggestion, it was just for show the problem as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

what you do is absurd…

you create a Button such as when you click on it you get inside `TwoPic()`:

```
button3 = Button(root, text = "2 Pics", command = TwoPic)
```

though you want to get the data inside `Lats` and `Longs` **before** they are defined.

You should instead be using the `Lats` and `Longs` from within `TwoPic`, once you have defined them. And for example show them in a `Label`, or as you already do, inside `print` statements.

Another solution:

```
class HandleLongLats:
    def __init__(self):
        self.longs = []
        self.lats = []

    def twoPic(self):
        run = 0
        while run < 2:
            run = run + 1
            print ("Start func TwoPic")
            oneMorePic()
            self.lats.append(finalLatSecondPhoto)
            self.longs.append(finalLongSecondPhoto)

            print '\n\nYour coordinates: ' + rippedLatitudeTwo + ',-' + rippedLongitudeTwo
            print "Below are the 2 new lats and longs in a list"
            print self.lats
            print self.longs
            root.quit()
        self.showList()

    def showUI(self):
        root = Tk() 

        label = Label(root, text="Choose Iterations", font=('Calibri', 12))
        button1 = Button(root, text = "0 Pics", command = Quit)
        button2 = Button(root, text = "1 Pic", command = onePic)
        button3 = Button(root, text = "2 Pics", command = self.twoPic)

        label.pack()
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
        button3.pack()
        root.mainloop() 

    def showList(self):  
        print "List: "
        print self.lats, self.longs # Should print my list....I'm now outside of the function
```

Here the idea is to make `lats` and `longs` members of a class, so you can use them from within another function.

Comment: Thanks Zmo. I have tried your code and I'm a little confused. The GUI doesn't pop up on its own as expected, so I tried: showUI() but it doesn't start it. How do I actually start it the class?

Comment: @zmo : please make sure the code you post is not *obviously* buggy. Like, instancemethods expect `self` as first param... :-/

Answer (score 0):

You try to reach variables which are out of the scope at the place where you try to print them. In your code you can only access those variables inside the function. There are 3 solutions to your problem.

1: make them gloabl like:

```
def TwoPic():
    run = 0
    global Lats = []
    global Longs = []
    [...]
```

2: define the variables outside the function

```
Lats = []
Longs = []
def TwoPic():
    run = 0 
    [...]
```

3: return them from the function